# How to calculate if there is no data I want هى

Tags: excel, graph, powerbi, dashboard

| Date | Camp | Visitors |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10/1/2023 | A | 500 |
| 10/1/2023 | C | 200 |
| 10/2/2023 | A | 100 |
| 10/2/2023 | B | 50 |
| 10/2/2023 | C | 100 |
| 10/3/2023 | A | 500 |
| 10/3/2023 | B | 150 |
| 10/3/2023 | C | 120 |
| 10/4/2023 | A | 123 |
| 10/5/2023 | B | 142 |
| 10/5/2023 | C | 426 |
| 10/6/2023 | B | 414 |

Suppose this table contains the data we obtained for the number of visitors to each camp

I want to calculate ** how many camps and name camps** that no Visitors

For example, if you  chose  date 10/1/2023
The number of camps is 1, and Camp B
In case I set another date
10/4/2023
The number of Camps is 2 and  Camp  A and B
**and What is my best graph for that ?**
And the second question

Bring all the names of all the camps and what are the dates that no Visitors

What is my best graph?

Comment: Do you literally want someone to help you pick out a visual method of analyzing your data?  Or do you need help with some coding that you didn't specify

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Pivot Table and the blanks would be camps with no visitors each date:

[image]

> [Create a PivotTable to analyze worksheet
> data](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576)